# Generate mp3 file from espeak

Tags: text, text-to-speech

I'd like to convert an text file to an mp3 file using espeak. Is it possible to do this? I'm trying to use espeak to create a song synthesis shell script that can convert text to a song.

Comment: I think this page explains how to generate mp3 files (at least partially): https://npmjs.org/package/espeak

Comment: And here's an explanation of how to do this using a shell script: http://eceppda.github.com/nerdterm/2011/11/23/ESPEAK.html

Comment: Also, it's possible to do pitch shifting using a program called rubberband.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this; if you just want a `wav` file, see the first example, and for an `mp3` conversion see the second.

1) Feed `espeak` your text file using the `-f` option, then use the `--stdout` option and redirect its data stream to file to create a valid `wav` file that plays correctly in any audio player.

```
espeak -f mytext --stdout > myaudio
```

Result checked with the `file` command (`file myaudio`):

```
myaudio: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 22050 Hz
```

2) If you want an mp3 conversion you will have to use a program to convert your file (or simply save it in `audacity` and export it as mp3). I have used `ffmpeg` (the git version), but you can use any program and just change the options:

```
espeak -f myfile --stdout | ffmpeg -i - -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 final.mp3
```

Result checked with `file final.mp3`:

```
final.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

Comment: This works but the quality of espeak is hideous.  Can barely make out what it is saying.  Isn't there a way to use Amazon Poly or something .... understandable?

Comment: Use `man espeak` to adjust how it sounds.

Answer (score 6):

I actually wrote a script achieving this... and it ended up working quite well.

https://github.com/divVerent/ecantorix

Example: https://github.com/downloads/divVerent/ecantorix/sarastro.ogg

Comment: I can't tell if that's the best or the creepiest thing I've heard today. Good work.

Comment: This is not a direct reply to the question, but it is so crazy that it deserves an upvote anyway!

Answer (score 2):

espeak now has a -w option which outputs to wav
(It still would need to be converted to mp3 afterwards.)

```
espeak -f foo.txt -w foo.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--stdout` option to espeak will tell it to write the audio data to stdout instead of putting it through the audio device. From there you can pipe it into e.g. ffmpeg for conversion to the proper format.

Comment: Can you show any examples of this that you've found?

Comment: I haven't found any; I just understand how programs work.

Comment: This question is perhaps relevant as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762164/how-to-make-computer-sing