# How to add more Languages\Voices to `Espeak`?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, sound, language-support, espeak

I've installed `Espeak` and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554747/how-to-install-more-voices-to-espeak) & [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178736/generate-mp3-file-from-espeak). But still I need more !

How to get Indian Languages\Voices and so other languages like French, German,UK-English,etc.,?

I tried to change the Language\Voice, by typing this`espeak --compile=fr`.
But it says `can't access`

Hence, How to change the Language\Voice?

How to make it to read a sentence or a paragraph?

Please do give also some useful Tips\Commands regarding `Espeak` like adding,sorting,reading text files and so on... ?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to download the language packs off the languages you need there is also a dictionary available  here is what might help you out [How can I install one language by command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149876/how-can-i-install-one-language-by-command-line)